# Centering text in Gosu

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I've been having trouble centering text in the Gosu library to the absolute middle of the screen.

```
require 'gosu'

class GameWindow < Gosu::Window
  def initialize (width=800, height=600, fullscreen=false)
    super
    self.caption = 'Hello'
    @message = Gosu::Image.from_text(
        self, 'HELLO WORLD', Gosu.default_font_name, 45)
  end

  def draw
    @message.draw(377.5,277.5,0)
  end
end

window = GameWindow.new
window.show
```

My first approach was to take the `height` of the screen, subtract it by the height of the text `45`, and then divide by 2. Now that seemed to work when aligning vertically.

[image]

However, horizontally is a different story...It seems to 
be taking the top left corner of the text and centering it which I expected it to do, instead of the middle of the text.

[image]

Anyone got a formula for this ? I tried a whole bunch of things, and only came close.

Comment: Have you tried [`draw_rot`](https://www.libgosu.org/rdoc/Gosu/Image.html#draw_rot-instance_method)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class GameWindow < Gosu::Window
  def initialize (width=800, height=600, fullscreen=false)
    super
    self.caption = 'Hello'
    @message = Gosu::Image.from_text(
        self, 'HELLO WORLD', Gosu.default_font_name, 45)
  end

  def draw
    @message.draw(377.5,277.5,0)
  end
end
```

Your `@message` is an instance of `Gosu::Image`

As far as I can see, the class has a method that allows you to align the image's rotational center to a specified point, [`draw_rot`](https://www.libgosu.org/rdoc/Gosu/Image.html#draw_rot-instance_method)

Using `draw_rot` instead of `draw` should work for you once you've found the center of the frame.

Comment: I tried `@message.draw_rot(377.5,277.5, 0, center_x = 0.5, center_y = 0.5)` But it appears to still be off http://puu.sh/jLR2r/a85482b491.png

Comment: @IZUHU where did you get the point coordinates? I imagine `277.5` is a bit off `300` (half the window height) because of the bar above the window but where does `337.5` come from? Shouldn't the horizontal position closer to `400` or simply `400`?

Comment: Ohhhhh!! See I was subtracting the font size `45` from the from the screen width before dividing `2`. I thought maybe centering the text object was similar to how you would do it in css. In css you would take the size of a `container` subtract if from the `width`, and then divide by `2`. Alternatively when I didn't see that working I multiplied `45` by the amount of characters in the string. I assumed that each character was 45 pixels, then I subtracted it from the width finally dividing by `2`. I was doing this whole thing wrong haha!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was having this issue earlier today and came up with this solution.

```
  def draw_centered_text(text, size, font)
    centered_text = Gosu::Image.from_text(text, size, {:width => WIDTH, :align => :center, :font => font})
  end
```

The above function converts the passed text to an image with a width equal to WIDTH (which in my case is a constant that stores the window width) and the text centred. You can then call the function like so:

```
draw_centered_text("Your text", 20, "Arial Bold").draw(0, 50, 0, 1, 1, Gosu::Color::WHITE)
```

You can replace 20 and 50 with any line height (font size) and y-position you want, just as you can change "Arial Bold" to "Arial" or any other font on your system. However, keep the 0 for the x-position (first parameter of `draw()`), since the centred text image is the same width as the window width.

See the links below for further information on `from_text()` and `draw()`:

- https://www.rubydoc.info/github/gosu/gosu/Gosu/Image#from_text-class_method
- https://www.rubydoc.info/github/gosu/gosu/Gosu/Image#draw-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never...

No need to convert your text to an image. Just center the text using two parameters available on the Font.draw_text_rel method: rel_x and rel_y. See your code (modified a bit) below.

See: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/gosu/Gosu%2FFont:draw_text_rel

```
require 'gosu'

class GameWindow < Gosu::Window
  def initialize (width=800, height=600, fullscreen=false)
    super
    self.caption = 'Hello'
    # @message = Gosu::Image.from_text(
    #     self, 'HELLO WORLD', Gosu.default_font_name, 45)
    @font = Gosu::Font.new(45)
    @message = "HELLO WORLD"
  end

  def draw
    @font.draw_text_rel(@message, width / 2, height / 2, 1, rel_x = 0.5, rel_y = 0.5)
  end
end

window = GameWindow.new
window.show
```